# Can't compile project using OpenCV debug build with msvc

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-code

```sh
opencv_world451d.lib 
helloworld.obj 
helloworld.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl cv::imshow(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,class cv::_InputArray const &)" (?imshow@cv@@YAXAEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@AEBV_InputArray@1@@Z) referenced in function main
C:\Users\kaito\OneDrive\Documents\Cpp\OpenCVHelloWorld\helloworld.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

When I use OpenCV debug build `opencv_world451d.lib`, vscode
won't compile my project. If I switch to OpenCV release build `opencv_world451.lib`, then everything is fine.

This is very odd since I used exact the same setting with Visual Studio 2019 and everything was OK with either debug or release build. CMake also build it.

This is my `tasks.json`

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: cl.exe build active file",
            "command": "cl.exe",
            "args": [
                "/Wall",
                "/Zi",
                "/EHsc",
                "/Fe:",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
                "${file}",
                "/I",
                "C:/Program Files/opencv/build/include",
                "/link",
                "/LIBPATH:C:/Program Files/opencv/build/x64/vc15/lib",
                "opencv_world451d.lib"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$msCompile"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "presentation": {
                "reveal": "always"
            },
            "detail": "compiler: cl.exe"
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there any setting need to be set properly when use debug build?

Comment: the 'd' is for debugging. You may have to add a few more arguments in it to compile.

Comment: You need to set the runtime to match the runtime used in the opencv library

Answer (score 1):

I solve the problem by use compiler flag /MDd instead of /MD. Looks like debug build needs the proper debug runtime.